# python trying to understand callstacks

Tags: python, callstack

I am trying to understand the callstack of the code below and I can't answer it.

Why does this line return 4:

```
7. return z
```

and why is this line 5:

```
16 x = x + m1(x)
```

Hope you can help me.

```
1  def m1(x): 
2      x = x + 1
3      z = m2(x, 4)
4      x = x + 1
5      z = z + 1
6      print(x)
7      return z
8 
9  def m2(x, y):
10     x = x + 1
11     y = y + 1
12     print(x, y)
13     return x
14
15 x = 1
16 x = x + m1(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you need to know is that variables inside functions are different from variables outside functions. Or more precisely, each time a function is called, a new set of variables is created just for that function call, with no relation to any variables anywhere else that might happen to have the same name. (With rare exceptions.) So, for example, if you wrote

```
def f1(x): 
    x = x + 1
    return x

x = 1
x = f1(x)
x = f1(x)
print(x)
```

there are actually three separate variables named `x`: there's the one at the top level ("global"), which is initialized to 1, the one created for the first call to `f1`, and the one created for the second call to `f1`. If you annotate their names to distinguish them from each other, here's effectively what happens:

```
x_global = 1

# Python does this behind the scenes
f1_call1_argument1 = x_global
# call f1
x_f1_call1 = f1_call1_argument1
# now your code in f1 starts running
x_f1_call1 = x_f1_call1 + 1
f1_call1_return_value = x_f1_call1
# return from f1
x_global = f1_call1_return_value

# now repeat but with the second call to f1
f1_call2_argument1 = x_global
x_f1_call2 = f1_call2_argument1
x_f1_call2 = x_f1_call2 + 1
f1_call2_return_value = x_f1_call2
x_global = f1_call2_return_value

print(x_global)
```

From this you can see how the different variables are kept apart, even though they have the same name in the code. Each variable has its own "area" of sorts in which the name refers to that variable, and in a different "area", the same name refers to a different variable. This is called [scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

---

I mentioned that there were some exceptions. Here are two somewhat common ones:

- Python lets you put a "global declaration" inside a function when you want that name to refer to the same thing inside the function as it does outside the function. So if I defined `f2` like this:

  ```
  def f2():
      global x
      x = x + 1
      return x
  ```

  then there would be no function-specific ("local") version of `x`. It would just use the global `x`. Running this code

  ```
  x = 1
  x = f2()
  x = f2()
  ```

  would work like so:

  ```
  x_global = 1

  # call f2
  x_global = x_global + 1
  f2_call1_return_value = x_global
  # return from f2
  x_global = f2_call1_return_value

  x_global = x_global + 1
  f2_call2_return_value = x_f1_call2
  x_global = f2_call2_return_value
  ```
- You can also have a default value for an argument, and because of a design decision in the way Python is implemented, the default value is effectively stored in an invisible variable that persists between function calls. If I have

  ```
  def f3(x=[]):
      x.append(5)
      return x

  x = [1]
  x = f3()
  x = f3()
  ```

  (I'm using a list because it can change, but an integer can't) then it works like this:

  ```
  # as part of the definition of f3
  f3_argument1_default = []

  x_global = [1]

  # first call to f3
  f3_call1_argument1 = f3_argument1_default
  x_f3_call1 = f3_call1_argument1
  x_f3_call1.append(5)                      # f3_argument1_default is now  [1,5]
  f3_call1_return_value = x_f3_call1
  x_global = f3_call1_return_value

  # second call to f3
  f3_call2_argument1 = f3_argument1_default
  x_f3_call2 = f3_call2_argument1
  x_f3_call2.append(5)                      # f3_argument1_default is now  [1,5,5]
  f3_call2_return_value = x_f3_call2
  x_global = f3_call2_return_value
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is because variable x and z are immutable.
In python, when we pass immutable arguments to a function, call by reference is no more applicable.
As soon as we change the value of such variable, functions makes its own copy i.e. local variable. This is the reason behind this.
 [Please refer this for more information](https://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php)